# Accessing values of a given object

Tags: java, oop

I am wondering why i have to deal with two types of arguments;that of a constructor and that of a method.For instance i have this simple class that adds two numbers

```
class Calc{
private int x = 6;
private int y;
private char z = 'z';

public int getx(){
return x;
}
public char selfrecur(){
return this.z;
}
public int add(int one,int two){
return one + two;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Calc gx = new Calc();
System.out.println(gx.x);
System.out.println(gx.add(44,3));
System.out.println(gx.selfrecur());
}
}
```

That works,and wow,wasn't that great.Now,i have this idea of having the constructor provide the arguments and the function's work will be to do the heavy computations.For instance in my class Kalc

```
class Kalc{
//** This example won't work **
private int x;
private int y;
private int z;

public Kalc(int v1,int v2,int v3){
this.x = v1;
this.y = v2;
this.z = v3;

}
public int add(){
return newObject.x + newObject.y + newObject.z;
//Gets the values of a new object and add them up
}
public int multiply(){
return newObject.x * newObject.y * newObject.z;
//Gets the values of a new object and multiply them
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Kalc k = new Kalc(4,5,6);
System.out.println(k.add());
System.out.println(k.multiply());
}
}
```

I have been looking here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html for clues but so far nothing.Is this even possible?.

Edit

```
class Kalc{
private int x;
private int y;
private int z;

public Kalc(int v1,int v2,int v3){
this.x = v1;
this.y = v2;
this.z = v3;
}
public int add(){
return this.x + this.y + this.z;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Kalc k = new Kalc(4,5,6);
System.out.println(k.add);
}
}
```

Error

```
C:\ja>javac Kalc.java
Kalc.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(k.add);
                    ^
  symbol:   variable add
  location: variable k of type Kalc
1 error

C:\ja>
```

Comment: what is your exact Question ?

Comment: it should be `k.add()` not `k.add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` key word:

```
public int add(){
    return this.x + this.y + this.z;
}
```

You can use `this` key word inside non-static methods too.

About your edit:
`add` is a function (and **not** a member) of class `Kalc` so you can call it as a function only:

```
System.out.println(k.add());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the below

```
class Kalc{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    public Kalc(int v1,int v2,int v3)
    {
        this.x = v1;
        this.y = v2;
        this.z = v3;
    }
    public int add(){
        return x+y+z;
    }
    public int multiply(){
        return x*y*z;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kalc k = new Kalc(4,5,6);
        System.out.println(k.add());
        System.out.println(k.multiply());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is newObject?

You have instantiated an object with prescribed values.  If you want to add them with an instance method, try this

```
return this.x + this.y + this.z;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to print :

```
System.out.println(k.add());
```

Instead of :

```
System.out.println(k.add);
```

as in the second case the compiler show `k.add` as `add` variable 
but in the first case `add()` the compiler show `add()` as a function which you define in Kalc Class